# Asynchronous functions in Typescript/Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, promise, es6-promise

I am having trouble when nesting two functions. The second function is executing before the first one finished. 
I have the two methods:

```
doLogin() {
    return this.authService.doLogin();
}
 toLogin(){
    this.router.navigateByUrl("/secure");
}
```

The first function doLogin() takes awhile because of the service. How can i make the second function, toLogin() only execute after doLogin() has finished and returns true (using promises, or callbacks)?

I am new to angular and javascript, so please be thorough in your explanation.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by using promise

```
doLogin() {
    return this.authService.doLogin().then(function(result){
        toLogin();
    });
}
```

you need to return a promise in this.authService.doLogin()